# ProgressDialog - cannot resolve symbol `ProgressDialog`

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, progressdialog

I would like to use a ProgressDialog in my app when the user tap on a login button. Problem I have is that ProgressDialog is not found - red text in AS. Is any library which I have missed?

**Gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Thanks

Comment: post your java code and logcat error block ..

Comment: It shows a red text in activity (that something like ProgressDialog) does not exist

Answer (score 3):

Try to input `import`  manually:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did nothing.